# How delete Documentation "iOs 4.2 Library" in XCode 4

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4

HI. My XCode 4.0.1 have a lot of documentation downloaded. I have

- iOS 4.2 Library
- iOS 4.3 Library
- Mac OS X 10.6 Core Library
- Mac OS X Legacy Library (uninstalled)
- Xcode 4.0 Developer Library

I want to uninstall 4.2 Library because it is old. But the "minus" sign is disable and "Delete Documentation Feed" is disable too. So, there are no other way to delete it.

Someone know how to do this?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Xcode 4:

1. Open Xcode Preferences
2. Click to highlight the docset you want to delete
3. Click the rectangle with a filled triangle icon.  It's next to the + and - icons at the bottom of the list of docsets
4. Click the hyperlink to show the docset in the finder.
5. Move or delete the docset.  You will likely need administrator privileges for this.

I recommend you move them to a temporary location.  Especially for older documentation, you may have to install old versions of Xcode to get them back.

UPDATE for Xcode 5:

1. Navigate to ~/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets/
2. Move or delete the docset.  You may need administrator privileges for this.

Comment: Wow.. very easy now... Why apple disable this things... It's a little obscure way to do it.

Comment: Probably just Xcode 4 growing pains.  The real reason you can't delete is because of permissions I think.  A future version of Xcode will likely just ask for administrator password...

Comment: PS: It's very easy download the deleted library, because it still in xcode.

Comment: I also found a bunch of obsolete Xcode docsets in the finder which take ~300MB each — worth deleting as well.

Answer (score 3):

Go to XCode Settings, Documentation tab. Select required documentation set and press arrow up button in the bottom to reveal documentation info pane. There you'll see a link to docset location (was /Library/Developer/Documentation/DocSets/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleiOS4_2.iOSLibrary.docset on my Mac). Simply delete docset from the file system and restart XCode.